# Android application only works on my device

Tags: android, android-studio

my current android application only works as required on my device.

when any of my colleagues build the same `github` branch the app builds and installs ok however the compose navigation does not work

if i build an apk and distribute it to my team this works fine

we have compared `gradle.properties` and `local.properties` for all team members and these are identical to mine.

we are all using the same Android Studio version of

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Canary 2
Build #AI-222.4167.29.2221.9093980, built on September 22, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
```

what could be causing this issue?

what config are we missing?

the part of the app that does not work for my colleagues is that the compose navigation does not work, the app employs a backdrop with menu items that allow the user to navigate to other sections of the application. clicking on these menu items only works for me

Answer (score 1):

we resolved this issue by deleting the `.idea` folder of all my teams Android Studio installations